# HTTP 406 Response when submitting data through form

Tags: php, forms

When I submit data through my form I get a 406 Not Acceptable response.

This is the form:

```
<form method="post" action="ucp.php?action=p">


        <fieldset>

        <legend>Post Here:</legend>

            <label type="hidden" for="title">Title:</label><br />

            <input type="text" name="title"><br /><br />';


        $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or die('could not connect to mysql '.mysqli_connect_error());

        echo'<select id="category" name="category">';

        $query = "SELECT * FROM categories";

        $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {

            echo '<option value="'.$row['cat_id'].'">'.$row['name'].'</option>';

        }

        echo'</select><br /><br />';

        mysqli_close($dbc);



        echo'<label type="hidden" for="post1">Post Content:</label><br />

        <textarea rows="4"  name="post1" id="post1" cols="50"></textarea><br />

        </fieldset>

        <input type="submit" value="Save Post" name="submit" />     

    </form>
```

This is what I'm trying to submit:

```
Planning on making more updates to the site. These include:

[code]
Adding status update to profile page (User can update their status, kind of like a skype mood message)
[/code]
```

If I put (almost) anything else in it comes out correctly and submits to the database but this gives me the 406 error. I tried disabling Mod Security but that isn't allowed by my host.

EDIT:

When I remove the ':' from what is being submitted it works.

Comment: Contact your web host. This sounds like a badly constructed web application firewall rule.

Comment: @duskwuff They won't turn off Mod security

Answer (score 0):

Read your code. You appear to be missing

```
<?php
?>
```

In the appropriate places. Consequently you are submitting a mixture of html and php together. I'm not surprised that it is rejecting it. It probably thinks that you are trying to inject the system.

The lines between mysql_connect and mysql_close are php code. I have no idea what that final echo is doing.

Comment: .-. Obviously you don't see the PHP tags as this is **NOT** the whole code.